# Rails: How to retrieve an attribute from a related model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model, attributes

I seem to be stuck with a problem that probably should be more obvious to me: How can I get certain attributes from a related model to show in a view.

In my application there are these 2 models:

products
product_images

I'm writing this while I'm on the go and don't have the exact code available. However I created the necessary associations, so that a product `has_many` product_images and a product_image `belongs_to` a product. The image model has an url, a default (boolean) flag and of course the product_id.

In the product index view I'd like to display the default image for that product. For the sake of simplicity though let's just assume I'm fine with showing the first picture - conditions should be easy to introduce once this works.

So in my products index view there's something like this (again, just from memory):

```
@products.each do |p|
    <h3><%= p.name %></h3>
    <%= image_tag p.product_images.first.url %>
    <p><%= p.description %></p>
end
```

While the description and name of the product alone display just fine as soon as I include the image_tag my view breaks with a NoMethodError stating that url is an undefined method in Class Nil.
To keep it even simpler I got rid of the image_tag and just wanted to see the url printed in a paragraph - the problem remains of course.
If I just try to get `p.product_images.first` the view prints what I assume is some sort of ID for the object/model just fine, which tells me that the association itself is ok. So why does Rails think that the url attribute should be a method?

I also checked back with the rails console to see if this is the correct syntax to retrieve a related attribute. Like so (again, from memory - syntax errors possible):

```
p = Product.first
=> [successful - shows the first product]
p.product_images.first
=> [successful - shows the first image model]
p.product_images.first.url
=> [successful - shows me the single attribute, the url to the image]
```

As you can tell by now I'm very new to this and your help is very much appreciated. Of course I read the Rails documentation, however the Active Record Query Guide mostly focuses on getting data from the current model and I wasn't able to find what I'm obviously missing in my sample app.

Why does this work in the console but not in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably because one of your `Product` does not have any `ProductImage`.

You can correct this by adding a method in your `ProductsHelper` like so:

```
def product_image(product)
    return if product.product_images.blank?

    image_url = product.product_images.first.url
    return if image_url.nil?

    image_tag(image_url).html_safe
end
```

And then call it from your view like so:

```
@products.each do |p|
    <h3><%= p.name %></h3>
    <%= product_image(p) %>
    <p><%= p.description %></p>
end
```

Comment: Indeed. I didn't set an image for all of my products just yet. I didn't expect this to be rails' default behaviour. Does that mean I'd have to introduce similar helper methods for all related models that may be empty/non-existent? I thought has_many would cover the case of not having related models.

Comment: `has_many` sets the collection as `[]` when there are no children. When you do `.first` on empty children collection, you get a `nil`. Then, when `nil.url` is called it becomes a problem. Makes sense?Not sure how `has_many` could have resolved this problem.

Comment: @thirdsun could you mark the answer as correct if it solves your initial problem?

Comment: Of course, I'll do that once I'm back at home to try - but I'm pretty confident that this is the solution. It makes sense.
It's just that I could imagine a lot of cases where a related model might not exist - I didn't expect having to cover all those cases "manually". Well, I'm new to this though.